# How to access elements in an array of structs (not global)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Trying to continue with my assignment but would like to sidetrack and figure out how array of structs work. Not sure if I'm not looking hard enough but I can't seem to find an answer.

Let's say I have one source file, main.c

```
#include "data.h" //this contains the struct data.
newPerson person[20];

int mainMenu(){
    addName();      
}
void addName(){
    strcpy(person[0].firstName, "George");
}
```

Doing it this way, I'm able to access the array of struct, however isn't this method considered taboo since my array of person is a global variable?

I then tried moving the array initialization into the main function instead

```
#include "data.h" //this contains the struct data.

int mainMenu(){
    newPerson person[20];
    addName();      
}
void addName(){
    strcpy(person[0].firstName, "George");
}
```

Doing it this way, when I get to the addName() function, I get a 'person undeclared' error. How can I access the person[] array outside of its function without making it a global variable? Thank for the help in advance. Below I have the example data.h included if needed.

data.h

```
typedef struct person{
    char firstName[20];
    char familyName[20];
    char telephoneNum[20];
}newPerson;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass parameters to the `addName()` function.

Example

```
#include "data.h" //this contains the struct data.

int mainMenu(){
    newPerson person[20];
    addName(person, 0, "George");      
}

void addName(newPerson *person, unsigned int index, const char *const name) {
    if ((person == NULL) || (index >= 20))
        return; /*                     ^ this number could be specified with a macro */
                /*                       or via a parameter                          */
    strcpy(person[index].firstName, name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, and if I wanted to use the addName function in someFunction(), wouldn't I still get the "person is undeclared" error? Also, how would

Comment: You need to pass the parameters to `someFunction()` too, if you got a lot of variables  you can use a `struct`, and then pass it to all the functions that will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, pass the variable, person in this case.

person is an array of struct newPerson.

to pass arrays as parameters you should define the function like this

```
//Option 1, the last dimension without number
void addName(newPerson person[]){
    //...
}

//Option 2, as a pointer, but it neets a cast on the call (newPerson*)
void addName(newPerson *person){ //I prefer option 1
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why prefer option 1? and `newPerson person*` is wrong.

Comment: newPerson *person, thanks!
I think tat if you are new to pass an array in a parameter its easier in that way.